# Determine whether or not the improper integral converges $\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^x}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I'm asked to determine whether or not the following improper integral converges.

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{e^x}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}} \ dx$$

I understand that I need to somehow find an upper bound for the integral but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Use $$x^{-1/3} \le e^x x^{-1/3} \le e \cdot  x^{-1/3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{3}}\leq\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{x^\frac{1}{3}}\leq\int_0^1\frac{e}{x^\frac{1}{3}}=e\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{3}}$
, it is sufficient to show that the integral
$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{3}}$ is convergence.\
$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{2}{3}|_0^1=\frac{2}{3}$.
Thus,
$\frac{2}{3}\leq\int_0^1\frac{e^x}{x^\frac{1}{3}}\leq\frac{2e}{3}$.